# Unable to start Docker Container in Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I have created a simple docker file to deploy a war in tomcat

```
FROM tomcat
ADD your.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I tested locally and works. I tried building the image and pushed it to Bluemix. The docker image got pushed and I can see it in the dashboard, but while trying to start it up (By Clicking on it ), the Vulnerability assessment kicks off and it gives a warning symbol with an Incomplete text and I am unable to proceed further. Need pointers on how to go about this.
Steps followed -

From my local m/c where I have docker running

```
# docker tag testimagetom registry.ng.bluemix.net/shabsctr/testimagetom:image_tag
# docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/shabsctr/testimagetom:image_tag
# cf ic run --name shabstrydocker registry.ng.bluemix.net/shabsctr/testimagetom:image_tag
```

Comment: Did the VA find anything? If yes, please update your question providing what it found. If not, you should wait for it to complete.

Comment: Click on "View the vulnerability report for this image" and comment what is the issue reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can build images with DockerFile by cf command. It'll create your image on your bluemix registory.

```
cf ic build [--tag|-t TAG_NAME] [--no-cache] [--pull] [--quiet] LOCAL_DOCKER_FILE_PATH
```